# AWS:Which language should the Lambda function be written so that lambda can access/invoke the .so file (dynamic library in linux)

Tags: java, aws-lambda, java-native-interface

We use AWS Lambda functions written in Java today which access Jar files; but now we have new following requirement

We have shared library (.so file). We like to expose functionality of this .so file via Lambda function and API gateway.

Which language should the Lambda function be written so that the lambda can access/invoke the .so file functionality most efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continute to use Java. Shared Objects are nothing but compiled libraries (developed in C++/ or C language usually). The library can be invoked via JNI interface from your existing Java code.
Frequently seen  scenario is when android apps/SDKs (Java) use/invoke shared objects (developed or provided by third parties)

Example:

```
static {
    try {
        System.load("/path_to_sso/my.so");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError unsatisfiedlink) {
        //handle it
    }
}
```

Refer this link:

[How to Load a Java Native/Shared Library (.so)](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Linux.asp)